# How to make the Panel // WP-Admin lighter via Mobile

Tags: wp-admin, admin, dashboard, performance, mobile

By accessing the WordPress Admin Panel.

via Cell/Mobile the loading is too slow.

And the layout is not responsive.

In Chrome console I get the following errors

```
[Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 622ms
admin-bar.min.js?ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:2 [Violation]     
Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' 
event.     Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page 
more     responsive. See 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
(anônimo) @ admin-bar.min.js?ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:2
onloadwff.js:71 [Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 565ms
12[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler levou <N> ms
jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2 [Intervention] Slow network is detected. See 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more details. 
Fallback font will be used while loading: https://SITE.com.br/wp- 
content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/eicons/fonts/eicons.woff2?5.16.0
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 945ms
twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/14.0.2/2b50.svg:1          GET 
https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/14.0.2/2b50.svg 404 (Not Found)
Image (assíncrono)
callback @ wp-emoji-release.min.js? 
ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:3
parse @ wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:3
f @ wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:5
s @ wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:5
n @ edit.php?post_status=draft&post_type=post:71
web-client-content-script.js:1 [Violation] 'message' handler took 
16898ms
twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/14.0.2/1f4b2.svg:1          GET 
https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/14.0.2/1f4b2.svg 404 (Not Found)
Image (assíncrono)
callback @ wp-emoji-release.min.js? 
ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:3
parse @ wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:3
f @ wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:5
s @ wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=94d95e86f39be5d8b6ee9e5e0d817b75:5
n @ edit.php?post_status=draft&post_type=post:71
web-client-content-script.js:1 [Violation] 'message' handler took 2784ms
96[Violation] 'setInterval' handler levou <N> ms
```

The Admin Page is standard for both devices.
I've been using WordPress for a long time and I don't see this issue being discussed.
— > The fact of loading gets worse when the posts session is accessed.

What is the effective way to have a faster page load via mobile?
Is it possible to put the scripts to asynchronous format?
Is there an AMP for the Wordpress dashboard?

**APP**

In the App the loading is stable.
The absence of the option to select All Posts is a big problem. Well, it forces you to post one by one.
So the application is more than 50% obsolete.
Because, many users need this function for batch publishing.

**SYSTEM**

test details
android system
Browsers: Chrome, Opera and Microsoft Edge
Connection: 3G/Wifi

Comment: This sounds like a question about server configuration/hosting set up more than one about WordPress; WordPress isn't what's slow here - it's either your server or the third-party code which you've added to WordPress. It's unclear what you mean by "the app," unless you're talking about the third-party WordPress mobile app which is developed by Automattic. Please note that both server configuration as well as third-party products are off-topic here.

Comment: @bosco, the user came here guided by me because the [question](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/564224/137387) was off topic on Stack Overflow in Portuguese. Could you please point the user to the Q&A where he can at least discuss the issue at hand.